# VS Code doesn't find expected dotnet SDK

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, sdk

I am running VS Code on Linux Mint ( 21.1 Vera ).
I am developing a small dotnet web app using C#.

Everything was running fine until ( I believe ) there was a dotnet sdk update.

I can see the current dotnet version from the terminal: 7.0.302

```
dotnet --list-sdks
7.0.302 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

When trying to run or build the project that was working until the update, I get this message:

```
dotnet run

You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.302/dotnet.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '7.0.5' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/

No frameworks were found.

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&    framework_version=7.0.5&arch=x64&rid=linuxmint.21.1-x64
```

So I follow the last link to install the missing framework.

It eventually takes to a command to install the SDK:

```
sudo apt-get update && \ sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

It doesn't let me specify 7.0.5, so it just reinstalls the most recent version, which is 7.0.302, and I am back to square one.

I have found a command to install 7.0.5 specifically, but it throws an error:

```
./dotnet-install.sh --architecture x64 --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet/ --runtime dotnet --version 7.0.5

dotnet_install: Error: Failed to verify the version of installed `.NET Core Runtime`.
Installation source: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/7.0.5/dotnet-runtime-7.0.5-linux-x64.tar.gz.
Installation location: /usr/share/dotnet/.
Report the bug at https://github.com/dotnet/install-scripts/issues.
dotnet_install: Error: `.NET Core Runtime` with version = 7.0.5 failed to install with an error.
```

It doesn't find a .NET runtime because I don't have one installed ( and never have ). But, from what I understand, SDK already included a runtime?

Ideally I would like to just tell VS Code to use 7.0.302, but happy to stick to 7.0.5 if I can find it anywhere. I still haven't managed...

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: It is a bit confusing, but SDK 7.0.302 includes Runtime 7.0.5. See under "Included runtimes" at https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0. What is the output of dotnet --list-runtimes ?

Comment: @nikstra - I thought it was the case, but I assumed I was wrong! Anyway, dotnet --list-runtimes returns nothing. Not an error, just no runtimes

Comment: @nikstra - Thank you for your comment! I had no idea runtimes had to be present too, I looked for a solution to the lack of runtimes returned and it if fixed my original issue :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem a few minutes after posting the issue...

The steps that worked for me are from https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699

The steps are from mixed state scenario 1.
Copied here in case the link is no longer available in the future:

Remove all .NET packages

```
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet*
sudo apt remove --purge aspnetcore*
```

Delete PMC repository from APT, using any of the typical methods, for instance by deleting the repo .list file

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
```

Update APT

```
sudo apt update
```

Install .NET SDK 6.0

```
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

Comment: I was about to suggest that you should try to uninstall/reinstall. I'm glad that you found a solution.